# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I am trying to work on functionality that will be able to drag multiple divs and combine it is as one (the contents in it) and drop it into the other column. In trying to do so I put a functionality check which is identifying basically which div should be changed and whether it gets merged or not. I am getting this error while setting the value in my state. I try a few ways but it's somehow showing this error. This will be passed as a prop to another child component. Can please him in identifying the problem.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

```
const finalValueUpdate = (
  finalValue, 
  task, 
  column, 
  selectedTaskIds, 
  tasks) => {
  if (finalValue === false && column.id == 'done') {
    console.log('check1');
    this.setState({ bigFinalValue: task.word }).bind(this);
  }
  else if(
    column.id == 'done' && 
    selectedTaskIds.length > 1 && 
    typeof bigFinalValue !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('check2');
    tasks.map((task, index) => {
      if(selectedTaskIds.includes(task.id)) {
        this.bigFinalValue += task.word + ' ';
        }
      })
  }

}

export default class Column extends Component<Props> {
  state = {
    selectedTaskIds: this.props.selectedTaskIds,
    finalValue: this.props.finalValue,
    bigFinalValue: '',
  };


  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props) {
    if (prevProps.selectedTaskIds !== this.props.selectedTaskIds) {
      this.setState({ selectedTaskIds: this.props.selectedTaskIds });
    }
  };


  render() {
    const column = this.props.column;
    const tasks = this.props.tasks;
    const selectedTaskIds = this.props.selectedTaskIds;
    const draggingTaskId = this.props.draggingTaskId;
    const finalValue = this.props.finalValue;
    
    return (
      <Container>
        <Title>{column.title}</Title>
        <Droppable droppableId={column.id} isCombineEnabled={true}>
          {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <TaskList
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              isDraggingOver={snapshot.isDraggingOver}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
            >
              {tasks.map((task, index) => {
                const isSelected = Boolean(
                  getSelectedMap(selectedTaskIds)[task.id]
                );
                const isGhosting =
                  isSelected &&
                  Boolean(draggingTaskId) &&
                  draggingTaskId !== task.id;
                

                if (finalValue === false && column.id == 'done') {
                  console.log('check1');
                  this.setState({ bigFinalValue: task.word }).bind(this);
                  console.log(this.state.bigFinalValue);
                }
                else if(
                  column.id == 'done' && 
                  selectedTaskIds.length > 1 && 
                  typeof bigFinalValue !== 'undefined') {
                  console.log('check2');
                  tasks.map((task, index) => {
                    if(selectedTaskIds.includes(task.id)) {
                      this.bigFinalValue += task.word + ' ';
                      }
                    })
                } 

                console.log("selectedTaskIds", selectedTaskIds);
                console.log('finalValue', finalValue);
                console.log('bigFinalValue', this.bigFinalValue);
                // for the console log of data incoming from the server
                console.log("==>", tasks);

                return (
                  <Task
                    task={task}
                    columnId = {this.props.column.id}
                    index={index}
                    key={task.id}
                    selectedTaskArray = {tasks}
                    finalValue = {finalValue}
                    isSelected={isSelected}
                    isGhosting={isGhosting}
                    selectionCount={selectedTaskIds.length}
                    selectedTaskIds={selectedTaskIds}
                    bigFinalValue = {this.bigFinalValue}
                    toggleSelection={this.props.toggleSelection}
                    toggleSelectionInGroup={this.props.toggleSelectionInGroup}
                    multiSelectTo={this.props.multiSelectTo}
                  />
                );
              })}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </TaskList>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you shouldnt need to bind the react methods
```this.setState({ bigFinalValue: task.word }).bind(this);```
try
```this.setState({ bigFinalValue: task.word });```

Comment: Yes tried it won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good with class components and I suggest you use the functional component and it might fix your problem but I think the problem is this line

```
this.setState({ bigFinalValue: task.word }).bind(this);
```

I don't know why it throws this error but try using a functional component and update the state in a useEffect hook.

Comment: Yeah, other modules are based on the functional component method but since the use case for this module is best fitted with beautiful-dnd I am restricted to using this. On converting to the functional level it is causing some issues with the existing functionality.